# PHP Development tool for eclipse not working on Windows 7 64bit

Tags: php, eclipse, java, eclipse-pdt

I just downloaded PHP Development tools for eclipse and I cant open it, it opens an alert window:

```
a java runtime environment jre or java development kit jdk must
be available in order to run eclipse for PHP-developers
```

I installed both jre and jdk and I still get the same alert message.
I have Windows 7 ultimate 64bit running on my computer.

Comment: Not sure whether it might require you to restart the PC or not.

Comment: Tried to restart the PC. The problem still exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/288821/ or http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Windows_Example
That might solve it.

Answer (score 0):

please install jreX86, unstall jre64.  PHP Development tool(eclipse-php-3.0.2.v20120611144) is